# How to set a certain Custom Template to a Single Blog Post

Tags: posts, templates, blog, blog-page

I need to set a custom created template to be used whenever a single blog post is displayed.

I can see how to assign custom templates to pages under Page Attributes > Template, but how do I tell my WP site to use a custom template when displaying a single blog post?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no build in template assigment for indivual standar posts from edit screen. But you can assign templates for individual posts. There are several options:

**Use WordPress template hierarchy system**

Under the root folder of your theme you can create this files:

- single.php for all single posts of any type.
- single-post.php, if this file exists, it will be used for standard posts instead of single.php.
- single-{post-type}.php, if this file exists, it will only for `{post-type}` posts instead of single.php

**Use `template_include` filter**

Using `template_include` filter you can use any template file for single posts that meet your requeriments. For example, use the template `template-for-my-post.php` for post with ID 124:

```
add_filter( 'template_include', 'cyb_post_template');

function cyb_post_template( $template ) {
    if ( is_single( 124 )  ) {
        $new_template = locate_template( array( 'template-for-my-post.php' ) );
        if ( '' != $new_template ) {
            return $new_template ;
        }
    }
    return $template;
}
```

Comment: I tried it @cybmeta and technically it is `single-post.php` in WP ver 4.1. Not single-posts.php

Comment: Sorry for the typo, fixed.